# Apache Traffic Server Cluster 7.1.1

Tags: apache-traffic-server

i am trying to configure a cluster between two Apache Traffic Server, version 7.1.1, following the instructions on http://www.divedeepstaylong.com/admin-guide/configuration/multi-server-caches.en.html#full-clustering.

This is my records.config configuration for the cluster:

```
#######Cluster
LOCAL proxy.local.cluster.type INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.cluster.ethernet_interface STRING eth0
CONFIG proxy.config.cluster.rsport INT 8088
CONFIG proxy.config.http.cache.cluster_cache_local INT 1
CONFIG proxy.config.proxy_name STRING atsvsobjetos
#
CONFIG proxy.config.body_factory.template_sets_dir STRING  etc/trafficserver/body_factory
CONFIG proxy.config.ssl.server.ticket_key.filename STRING NULL
CONFIG proxy.config.log.config.filename STRING logging.config

CONFIG proxy.config.cache.ip_allow.filename STRING ip_allow.config
```

The 8080 tcp and 8088,8086,8089 udp ports are open in the firewall, but when I ask about the cluster, this is the answer:
    # bin/traffic_ctl metric get proxy.process.cluster.nodes

proxy.process.cluster.nodes 1

What I am doing wrong? somebody can help me? I am completely stuck!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Clustering was removed in ATS. You must now individually configure each node.